# Relation between entity doctrine. How to references "foreign key"?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm currently working with **Symfony** and **Doctrine** and I'm having a little bit of trouble to reference two entity.

I have a entity called `cinema` and another one called `theater`. It's a relation of OneToMany, where one cinema can have many theater.

I create a `cinema_id` into `theater` so I can relate cinema and theater.

I have create a controller to consume data from an API and store the data into a Postgres database. Here is the controller:

`TheaterController`

```
namespace App\Controller;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Entity\Cinema;
use App\Entity\Theater;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TheaterController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/theater", name="theater")
*/
public function Theater(Request $request)
{   
    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('GET','api-content');

    $arrayContent = json_decode($res->getBody());

    foreach ($arrayContent as $value)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $theater_cinema_id = $entityManager->getReference(Cinema::Cinema, $id);
        $theater->addId($theater_cinema_id);
        $theater_booking_cinema = 'value';
        $theater_booking_id = $value->id;

        $theater = new theater();
        $theater->setId($theater_cinema_id);
        $theater->setBookingCinema($theater_booking_cinema);
        $theater->setBookingId($theater_booking_id);
        //echo $theater;

        $entityManager->persist($theater);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
  }
}
```

My problem here is, how can I reference the `id` from `cinema` to the `cinema_id` from `theater`? What am I doing wrong?

The two entities are:

`Cinema`

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CinemaRepository")
*/

class Cinema
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $is_active;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created_at;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updated_at;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getIsActive(): ?int
{
    return $this->is_active;
}

public function setIsActive(int $is_active): self
{
    $this->is_active = $is_active;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->created_at;
}

public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
{
    $this->created_at = $created_at;

    return $this;
}

public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->updated_at;
}

public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
{
    $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

    return $this;
}
}
```

`Theater`

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TheaterRepository")
*/

class Theater
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cinema")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $cinema;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $booking_cinema;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $booking_id;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getCinema(): ?cinema
{
    return $this->cinema;
}

public function setCinema(?cinema $cinema): self
{
    $this->cinema = $cinema;

    return $this;
}

public function getBookingCinema(): ?string
{
    return $this->booking_cinema;
}

public function setBookingCinema(string $booking_cinema): self
{
    $this->booking_cinema = $booking_cinema;

    return $this;
}

public function getBookingId(): ?int
{
    return $this->booking_id;
}

public function setBookingId(int $booking_id): self
{
    $this->booking_id = $booking_id;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you have many cinemas in one theater. So, you have add the following code to your `Theater` entity:

```
// ...

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// ...

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $cinemas
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Theater", mappedBy="theater")
 */
public $cinemas;

// ...

/**
 * Theater constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->cinemas = new ArrayCollection();
}

// ...

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getCinemas(): array
{
    return $this->cinemas->toArray()
}

/**
 * @return Theater
 */
public function addCinema(Cinema $cinema): self
{
    $this->cinemas->add($cinema);

    return $this;
}

// ...
```

And the following code to your `Cinema` entity:

```
// ...

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Theater", inversedBy="cinemas")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="theater_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
 private $theater;

// ...
```

Then you can access to your `cinemas` entities from `Theater` entity:

```
$theaterRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Theater::class);
$theater = $theaterRepository->findBy(['id' => 1]);
$cinemas = $theater->getCinemas(); // array

/** @var Cinema $cinema */
foreach($cinemas as $cinema) {
    // ...
}
```

Or add new `Cinema` to your `Theater`:

```
$theaterRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Theater::class);
$theater = $theaterRepository->findBy(['id' => 1]);

$cinema = new Cinema();
// ...
$theater->addCinema($cinema)
// Persist, flush, e.t.c
```

About the `ArrayCollection` you can read [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/latest/index.html)

And you can access to your `Theater` entity from any `Cinema` entity:

```
$cinemaRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Cinema::class);
$cinema = $cinemaRepository->findBy(['id' => 1]);
$theater = $cinema->getTheater(); // Theater object
```

Or add the `Theater` to your `Cinema`:

```
$cinema = new Cinema();
$theater = new Theater();
// ...
$cinema->setTheater($theater);
// ...
// Persist, flush, e.t.c
```

Comment: This is the opposite in fact, read again the second line of the question : *one cinema can have many theater.*

Comment: Theater being a cinema room

Comment: Well, then by analogy, only in the reverse order. I'm too lazy to edit this answer again

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I understood. I'll create an array and function to get and add in this array in `cinema`.
After that, I will access `theater` from cinema and add new `theaters` to `cinema`. 
Is that it?

Comment: Yes, you are understand correct. But don't copy & paste my code. I have shown only example. Modify it for you needs

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine is an ORM, which means you don't have to think about tables, but entities. You don't think about foreign keys, but relations between entities.

Your API is giving you the cinema ID, or you can access it another way? You can retrieve the cinema using this :

```
$cinema = $entityManager->getRepository('App:Cinema')->findOneById($cinema_id);
```

You want to tell what cinema the theater belongs to? Use this :

```
$theater->setCinema($cinema);
```

Doctrine will itself build and execute the queries to get the desired datas.